# How to find derivative when x is in the exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Hi I was practicing for my final math IB exam and stumbled upon this calculus question where I have to find the derivative of a function whose x is written as an exponent. I'm not too familiar with the ln rule, and the answer I got was `4` which I believe is wrong. Could someone help me understand how to solve this step-by-step?
$$
f(x) = 4x+5^{0.4x}
$$

Comment: $$ \frac{d}{dx} \ \left[ \ a^{bx} \ \right] \ \ = \ \ b·(\ln a) · a^{bx} \ \ . $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)=4x+5^{0.4x}$
$f(x)=4x+5^{\frac{2x}{5}}$
$f'(x)=4.\frac{d}{dx}(x)+\frac{d}{dx}(5^{\frac{2x}{5}})$
$f'(x)=4+\ln(5).5^{\frac{2x}{5}}.\frac{2}{5}.\frac{d}{dx}(x)$
$f'(x)=2\ln(5).5^{\frac{2x}{5}-1}+4$